# Any way to wall off a thread's memory area?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a process which leaks memory. I know the causes of this, and have a solution. This is not what this question is about.

One way of removing the destructive effect of the memory leak would in my case be to run the many instances of this process, literally in separate processes, letting each one run its course and die a natural death, as it were. (each one only leaks a couple of megs)

However, this seems to involve a lot of overhead.

Any way to create a memory 'wall' in .NET? (other than to spawn a process) - Such that everything inside that wall could be torn down at will.

Of course, there are contrived answers to this involving some kind of meta memory system; not really what I'm looking for, unless it is super clever :)

Please no comments about how I should just fix the memory leak. (It's in the .NET framework)

Comment: Are you saying the framework has a leak?

Comment: Can you prove there is a leak in the framework? It's more likely to be in your code

Comment: Are threads not sufficient for this task?

Comment: @soandos the .net framework has had memory leaks in the past, and possibly still does. I do remember some in WinForms controls and I believe there is one in a WPF Grid Control in 3.5. Tom didn't give a lot of details, so there is a possibility that SELECT is broken.

Comment: I agree that in principle it is possible, but it would seem unlikely.

Comment: @drharris threads do not create a separate memory area afaik.

Comment: @soandos - I will endeavour to get back to you with some proof of my assertion. The results showing this were some time ago and I do not have the code here. If I remember correctly, it was only apparent after several hours of extremely intensive use on multiple threads. For most applications, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), though I also entreat you to fix the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think thats what I was looking for. As I explained in the comments above, we did fix the issue by replacing the leaking component.

Comment: I know appdomain offer thread and security boundaries but I didn't know that extended to memory as well. I had thought (though I could be wrong) that a process only had one managed heap.

Comment: Hmmm, well I will look into it. @Joel - can you confirm that this extends to memory?

Comment: "Application domains provide a more secure and versatile unit of processing that the common language runtime can use to provide isolation between applications. You can run several application domains in a single process with the same level of isolation that would exist in separate processes, but without incurring the additional overhead of making cross-process calls or switching between processes." 

Sounds like just what I was asking for.

Comment: However, will this clean up unmanaged resources that have leaked? It seems not.

Answer (score 6):

**Treat the cause, not the symptoms!**

Can you prove there is a leak in the framework (and have you submitted a Connect issue)? It's much more likely to be a memory leak in your code.

Download [memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/), [Redgate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (all have trial versions) and find and fix the actual problem.

Comment: Yes, we profiled the application, identified the leak, and fixed it by replacing the .NET component responsible. But my question is not about the memory leak.

Comment: @Tom: I'm confused. Do you still have a memory leak?

Comment: This is really the only correct solution. It might be "long winded" and difficult, but fixing the problem will make you a better programmer and be less contrived.

Comment: I have one piece of code which leaks. And one which doesn't. My question is about whether its possible to create an area of memory that can be trashed, without creating a separate process.

Comment: ...and my answer is the same: find the leak!

Comment: I would like to prove that the leak is in the framework, but the problem with that is that it is going to involve a fair amount of work in itself documenting the proof. I hope to get round to this soon.

Comment: As I explained, (see the edited first comment) we found the leak already!

Comment: @Tom: you said: "I have one piece of code which leaks. And one which doesn't." - so in one sentence you say you have a leak, and in the next say you haven't!  Which is it?

Comment: It's just that this question isnt about the leak. Its about a more general way to manage memory leaks in certain situations where a solution like this makes sense. If the .NET framework doesnt offer something like this, then I think it would be a good feature to have.

Comment: @Tom: OK, Is the component in the framework?  And if it is, have you submitted a Connect issue?

Comment: OK Mitch. Its a memory leak issue which is solved. However, solving issues like this can be very time consuming for developers, and sometimes impossible when the problem is not in code that they control. Sometimes simply saying to the runtime 'I want a lightweight process-like thread with its own memory area that I can tear down at any time', seems like an attractive idea.

Comment: I will endeavour to submit a Connect issue, and to come back to this question with more complete proof. :)

Comment: @Tom: that's essentially what a memory profiling tool does!  And I wouldn't call using memprofiler time consuming. One day, a dev rang me and asked if I could recommended a tool. I did (memprofiler). He called me back 10 minutes later: he had downloaded the trial, installed and found the leak in 10 minutes (literally)!

Comment: Google does this with Chrome, but not in .NET. The framework is not going to offer you much control over memory (being managed), but you could easily simulate this by simply spawning new processes and monitoring them. Your main process would simply keep track of each spawn and decide when to kill them.

Comment: Yes, the component is a core framework component. May I just add that IMHO .NET rocks, and I am not trying to badmouth anything. Every framework I've used has its fair share of issues and shortcomings, and .NET is amongst the best of the best. Will be back with some code to demonstrate so called 'memory leak' and you guys can rip me up. some fun. since this kind of thing is important to get into the open, and I am guilty of keeping bugs like this under my hat too long through sheer laziness. ;)

Comment: @dharris, yes I mentioned this as a possibility, however, the goal is to remain as lightweight as possible and consume as little CPU as possible.

Comment: Yes, we used memory profiling tools to fix it. However, as I said, when the bug is not in your code but in the runtime your program runs in, then it can be, in some cases, impossible to fix.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted (I cant yet anyway) but I would imagine its because you didnt quite answer the question, which was about walling off a memory area for use by possibly dodgy code, that cannot or will not be fixed for whatever reason. I specifically asked people not to tell me to fix the leak (as I've already done that). This is essentially a theoretical question, looking to expand my knowledge rather than solve a specific problem. Perhaps that is what you missed.

Comment: @Tom: np. I'm familiar with AppDomains and there (intended) use.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me then whether unmanaged resources allocated from framework code will be cleaned up when one is torn down.